# Trying to find specfic information using XPATH

Tags: xml, xpath

I want to find the names of movies published by the subsidiary with id WaltDisneyPictures after the year of 2010 having a screen time (running time) of more than 90 minutes.

I'm pretty new at this and I don't know what to do after. The root is Disney
[image]

```
/Disney/Subsidiaries
```

I'm pretty new and I've sat here for at least 29min, please can someone answer this question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
/Disney/Subsidiary[@id='WaltDisneyPictures']/Movie[Year > 2010 and ScreenTime[@unit='minutes'] > 90]/Name
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's your `xpath` query.

```
//Disney/Subsidiaries/Subsidiary[@id='WaltDisneyPictures']/Movie[Year>2010 and ScreenTime > 90]/Name
```